# DetailViewerField tooltip

Tags: smartgwt

I want to use the tooltip on the DetailViewerField. I tried to use DataSourceField.setPrompt() method on my data source and it works on ForItem's, but I can't set tooltip on the detail viewer field. 
Is it possible to set the tooltip on Detail Viewer Field?

Answer (score 1):

I looked for a solution for this and couldn't find an easy way. The only workaround I could find is described here:

http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8130&page=2